# Improving search results in qgis2web delimited text layer

Tags: qgis2web, search

I'm using QGIS 3.10.11 to generate a webmap using qgis2web. In the 'Export to webmap' (in export as OpenLayers) settings window, I am adding 'layer search' and selecting a csv text field for the search. The export runs OK.

When I open the map in a browser (MS Edge) and type a search term, the list of results returned includes many unwanted hits. This is because the search is finding any record which contains the letters in the search term. so a search for 'box' will return 'Box farm' but also returns 'Roxby farm Cottage'. I have tried entering the term in single and double quotes, but this returns  no hits. Clearly, the more text that is entered the better the results. However, some users will only enter 4 or 5 letters in the search box which causes the problem. I have about 2000 rows (records) in the csv file.

How can I force only a specific string of text to be returned in search results?